# How can I get git completion to show me commit names?

Tags: windows, macos, git, cygwin, zsh

There's something I don't understand about Git and completion in Zsh.

I am using a Windows machine with Git (v2.11. for Windows) and Cygwin with Zsh (with Babun). When I type `git checkout` and hit `TAB` twice, I get a completion prompt for branches and object names:

[image]

Pretty neat! Now, on my OS X machine with Git (2.13.0 for Mac, installed via Homebrew) and Zsh, when I type `git checkout` and hit `TAB` twice, I only get this:

[image]

**Where does the functionality in the first prompt come from?** In other words, what do I have to install under OS X / Zsh to make that happen?

Some things I tried:

- I've already ruled out that it's Oh-my-Zsh's `git` plugin doing it, because when I disable that under Windows/Cygwin, I still get the same fancy completion.
- All I have to do in Windows starting with an empty `.zshrc` to get this completion to work is to run `autoload -U compinit && compinit`
- I tried adding `fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/ $fpath)` to my `.zshrc` in the hope that it'd pick up what Homebrew installed (as mentioned in the `brew info git` output), but it didn't change anything.
- I tried installing `zsh-completions` from Homebrew, adding `fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh-completions $fpath)` to my `.zshrc` as suggested. Still no change.
- What confuses me even more is that recently, I used a MacBook from a colleague who didn't know much about Git. He had only Git installed. He got the same extended completion without having configured anything.
- My `.zcompdump`, if that helps: https://pastebin.com/raw/UzrZ2NqD
- My `.zshrc`: https://github.com/slhck/dotfiles/blob/master/.zshrc

Some more debugging output from OS X, when I type `git`, then `Ctrl-X`, then `h`:

```
tags in context :completion::complete:git::
    argument-1 options  (_arguments __git_zsh_main _git)
    use-compctl         (_default _git)
    globbed-files       (_files _default _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git:argument-1:
    alias-commands common-commands all-commands  (__git_zsh_main _git)
    alias-commands                               (__git_zsh_cmd_alias __git_zsh_main _git)
    common-commands                              (__git_zsh_cmd_common __git_zsh_main _git)
    all-commands                                 (__git_zsh_cmd_all __git_zsh_main _git)
```

Whereas when I do the same on Windows/Cygwin, I get:

```
tags in context :completion::complete:git::
    argument-1 options  (_arguments _git)
tags in context :completion::complete:git:argument-1:
    aliases main-porcelain-commands user-commands third-party-commands ancillary-manipulator-commands ancillary-interrogator-commands interaction-commands plumbing-manipulator-commands plumbing-interrogator-commands plumbing-sync-commands plumbing-sync-helper-commands plumbing-internal-helper-commands  (_git_commands _git)
```

Output of `ls -l ${^fpath}/_git`

```
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/completions/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/functions/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/brew/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/docker-compose/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/docker/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/gem/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git-extras/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git-flow/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/github/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/osx/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/python/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/rails/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/ruby/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/svn/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/vagrant/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /Users/werner/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/virtualenv/_git: No such file or directory
ls: /usr/local/share/zsh-completions/_git: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r--  1 werner  admin  336270 Dec 21 19:42 /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.3.1/share/zsh/functions/_git
lrwxr-xr-x  1 werner  admin      56 May 18 17:26 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git -> ../../../Cellar/git/2.13.0/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
lrwxr-xr-x  1 werner  admin      56 May 18 17:26 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git -> ../../../Cellar/git/2.13.0/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
lrwxr-xr-x  1 werner  admin      56 May 18 17:26 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git -> ../../../Cellar/git/2.13.0/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
```

Comment: Can you please check the zsh version numbers on both machines? With the current git version (5.3.1-dev-0) I get your desired behavior. The relevant completion function has a size of 336319 bytes (usually installed under `/usr/share/zsh/VERSION/functions/_git`, although I don't know anything about homebrew...).

Comment: I'm using 5.3.1 on the Mac. Does `.zcompdump` help in troubleshooting? See the pastebin link in my updated post.

Comment: There are several `_git` functions autoloaded according to your `.zcompdump`. Please provide the output of `ls -l ${^fpath}/_git`.

Comment: Added to the post. I also cannot get this kind of completion to work with a completely new user account, when I just open Terminal, enter `/usr/local/bin/zsh`, run `autoload -U compinit && ocmpinit`.

Comment: To be honest, that's not what I expected. My assumption was, that there are several `_git` completion functions in your `$fpath`, of which at least one is outdated. To rule out that you have some weird global config, can you run `zsh -f` (load almost no config files) and try again -- after `autoload -U compinit && compinit` of course. My `$fpath` in that case consists of `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`, `/usr/share/zsh/site-functions` and `/usr/share/zsh/5.3.1-dev-0/functions`.

Comment: Hm, no dice, my fpath being `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions /usr/local/Cellar/zsh/5.3.1/share/zsh/functions` in that case. Which does link to `../../../Cellar/git/2.13.0/share/zsh/site-functions/_git`. I'm thinking about nuking everything (at least Zsh, Git, and the various plugins) and starting from scratch…

Comment: Solved the issue, although I think it's a bug with whatever Homebrew does w.r.t. the Git completions it installs for Zsh.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what exactly was wrong, but here's what I did to solve the problem:

First, make sure to open Terminal and launch Bash (`/bin/bash`), then:

```
brew uninstall zsh
rm -rf /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
brew install zsh
```

---

Apparently, though, reinstalling Git will cause the same problem to occur again:

```
brew reinstall git
```

Once I do this, the completion is back  to its reduced form. If that is the case, you can remove the Homebrew-installed Git completions:

```
rm /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/git-completion.bash
rm -rf /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_git
```

This will make the extended completions show up again.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a very old thread, but I hope it helps the next person. There is a issue with the homebrew version of Git on OSX causing the git-extras completion to break. If you uninstall this version, it works again. You may be able to run another version, but the homebrew one is busted for sure, at least.

Edit:
I know the built-in version (git version 2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)) works fine. I have the latest version from HomeBrew 2.44.0

OS: macOS 12.6.3 21G419 arm64
Host: MacBookPro18,3
Kernel: 21.6.0
Terminal: iTerm2

Comment: Which version.  Please add tle version number to your answer.